# Browser ignores div specifing

Tags: html, css

The values of `‪#‎header‬ h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6` apply to all `h` tags (although these have a separated, general sheet).

It seems that `#header` is being ignored in someway.

Why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma delimits *complete selectors*.

The descendant combinator only connects `#header` to `h1`.

You need to repeat `#header` for each of the other elements you want it to combine with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify each h1 and h2 etc in that `#header` id, now you're having the h1 good, but the h2 etc not, because you will need it to be in the `#header` id. Like this:

```
‪#‎header‬ h1,‪#‎header‬ h2,#‎header‬ h3,#‎header‬ h4,#‎header‬ h5,#‎header‬ h6
```